# Client Configuration for Message Load Balancing

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have 6 AMQ instances (3 masters + 3 slaves) in clustering mode, each in a different machine.  Each instance has let's say `queue/ExampleQueue`.  We would like to achieve load-balancing as we have massive messages to be sent to `queue/ExampleQueue`.

[This example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/clustered/client-side-load-balancing/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example) uses `ConnectionFactory` only from one node.

In Spring we utilize the `ConnectionFactory` by configuring all 6 Node-ConnectionFactory-URLs:

```
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory: (tcp://vbox:61616,tcp://vbox:61716,tcp://vbox:61816,tcp://vbox:62616,tcp://vbox:62716,tcp://vbox:62816)?type=CF...
```

What would happen if we only configure 1 master node as follows:

```
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory: (tcp://vbox:61616)?type=CF...
```

1. Would this 1 master node do round-robin-load-balancing?
2. Does ist mean that in case of multiple brokers URL, there are tend to be more than 1 ConnectionFactory used? In our case, that would be 6 ConnectionFactory instances involved. Each of them will also has its own topology instance? Is it necessary to also put the 3 slave URls? What would happen if we set useTopologyuseTopologyForLoadBalancing=false?

Comment: What version of AMQ are you using?

Comment: Did you benchmark 1 instance vs. a cluster of 3 instances to determine that the cluster performed better?

Comment: When you say you "would like to achieve load-balancing" are you talking about client-side connection load-balancing or broker-side message load-balancing? The title mentions client-side load-balancing, but the question discusses having the broker (i.e. "node") do the load-balancing.

Comment: How many clients will you have connecting to the broker and how many connections will each application use?

Comment: 1. we are using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0.  2. no we havent.  3. yes, sorry for confusing title.  In fact it is about the broker-side message load-balancing.  4.  We have about 10 clients.  To be honest I dont know how many connections each application uses, we call every time the JMSTemplaet.doSend(...) from org.springframework.jms.core every time we want to send a message.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to clarify exactly what you're asking about (i.e. broker-side message load-balancing).

Comment: The edits you've made to your question have made it more confusing. You're title says "Broker-Side Message Load Balancing" but your question is all about the client configuration. Client configuration is not related to broker-side message load-balancing. The broker's configuration controls this, not the client's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing multiple brokers in the same URL is mainly useful when making the *initial* connection. Each broker in the list will be tried until a connection is successfully established. Then as soon as the client connects to any node in the cluster it will receive the topology of the entire cluster and any additional connections made with that same `ConnectionFactory` instance will be distributed across the cluster in a round-robin fashion based on the received topology.

The down side of just listing one broker in the URL is that if that one broker is down the client won't connect to anything at all.